# Node Express, avoid credentials in AJAX response

Tags: node.js, api, mongodb, express, mongoose

Say I have this:

```
exports.listUsers = function(req, res, next){
    userModel.find(function(err, users){
        if(err){
            return next(err);
        }
        return res.send(users);
    });
};
```

I'm going to be sending an array of `user` objects back down the wire to the client. Now another user can just open the network tab and see the fields: `email`, `password`, etc in the response. Will I have to be explicit in which fields I want returned from the Mongoose query or is there a way to prune out unwanted fields to send in the response? Which is the better approach?

Comment: Why make a global list public? Really not sure what you are asking here.

Comment: @NeilLunn ok, imagine more like a "user directory", for search purposes, like Follow/Unfollow...

Comment: All I am saying is "look at your code". A `.find()` with **no arguments**. Why? Can you just not supply a "filter" condition?

Comment: @NeilLunn, sure I can. But I'm asking is it best to explicitly say what you want or process the document and remove unwanted fields?

Comment: You seem to be looking for some kind of "redact" statement. This does not exist for MongoDB at current and to my knowledge there are no plans to do this at the "document" level (a field level implementation  is in the upcoming release as of writing). The natural progression of "filtering" results on a "document" level is to **filter** via your criterion. This seems to make common sense, and I fail to to see the validity of this question. If you are thinking more cerebral than others, then perhaps make your **question** clearer on this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On an "field" level (since we clarified that in conversation) what you probably want is [**`$redact`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#pipe._S_redact).

This is **not** available at the present time of writing, but however **will** be available in the upcoming 2.6 release and versions upwards.